# Capturing Text from tab selected in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

Am working on some tabs using Jquery, if the user clicks on 
a specific tab, am trying to capture the text of the tab selected
and do some action if the text of the tab clicked matches but it 
aint showing.

~ Kindly assist?

```js
let selected = false;
$(".columns").click(function () {
    if (selected =! selected) {
        var subject = $(this).text();
        //alert(subject);
        if(subject == "Mathematics"){
            alert('Maths');
        }
        else if(subject == "English"){
            alert('Eng');
        }
        else{
            alert('Others');
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Mathematics</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>English</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Swahili</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Religious</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you need to match based on tab text or could it be based on ID? What would happen if two tabs had the same name?

Comment: @Remy Want to match based on tab text,, the content is static so no tabs will have similar names..

Comment: What do you *think* this line is doing? `if (selected =! selected)`  - what do you get if you remove that `if`

Comment: @freedomn-m When I remove it and I alert(subject) clicked it is displayed twice,, so the selected variable captures the subject selected only when the tab is clicked once..

Comment: Well that's an XY problem, but not the one you've asked.  Maybe if you used clearer spaces it wouldn't be a question (`if (selected = !selected)`), but at least you know why it's there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is when you get the text it comes with spaces. use `.trim()` to remove them.

```js
let selected = false;
$(".columns").click(function () {
    if (!selected) {// means false
        var subject = $(this).text();
        //alert(subject);
        if(subject.trim() == "Mathematics"){
            alert('Maths');
        }
        else if(subject.trim() == "English"){
            alert('Eng');
        }
        else{
            alert('Others');
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Mathematics</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>English</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Swahili</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Religious</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Martin if you used `data-value='English'` then you wouldn't have to trim (and wouldn't have need to ask this question).  Never use `.text()` for anything other than displaying text to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is static, I would recommend adding IDs, as this enforces unique naming, however, to answer your question, if you're looking to match tabs by their name, I would suggest using XPath, as you can't select by text with CSS selectors

```
//*[text()="Mathematics"]
```

If you copy the above and paste it in dev tools, it should show the highlighted matches. To use it with jQuery, use

```
$(document).xpathEvaluate(//*[text()="Mathematics"])
```

To achieve the desired outcome with ID's, which is a better practice for this use case, you're simply matching to your ID as follows:

HTML:

```
<span ID="Mathematics">Mathematics</span>
```

CSS:

```
#Mathematics { }
```

JQuery:

```
$("#Mathematics")
```